# Is CMPedometer historical data lost on upgrade to iOS10 or a Restore?

Tags: ios, core-motion, healthkit, health-monitoring, pedometer

Does anyone know if CMPedometer historical data is normally lost on OS upgrade or phone restore? It is still there in Health Kit, but a pedometer query returns 0 from previous dates pre OS upgrade. Thanks in advance if you know about this.

Comment: This sounds like something you should file a bug with Apple for (https://bugreporter.apple.com).

Comment: OS updates do not clear the pedometer memory based on my experience. A phone restore, however, does. I don't think that this behavior is documented anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @FeichengMaike. I did a restore so it must be that.